# Find the total time spent by CPU in user mode, sys mode, and real mode

Tags: linux, unix, time, top-command

I am wondering if its possible to find out the total time spent by CPU in real mode, sys mode and user mode after the server came up.

Top command show the real time % usage, but I am trying to find out the total time spent by CPU since it came up.

Answer (score 0):

Does this article help?
http://www.linuxhowtos.org/System/procstat.htm

This is a Linux thing; I don't know of any other way in Unix, unless it has C2 auditing.